Isomorphism between linear functionals $\mathbb{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Problem: Show that if $\mathbb{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, the space of the linear functionals in $\mathbb{R}^2$, with the matrix norm $\|\cdot\|_p$ ($p > 1$) is isomorphic with the $\mathbb{R}^2$ space with the norm $\|\cdot\|_q$ of vectors, where $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$.
My try: (wrong) I think I got it for the case $p = q = 2$ (euclidean norm): If $F \in L(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is a linear functional, we can represent it by a $2 \times 1$ matrix representing its coefficients. Let $F(x, y) = ax + by$, the 2-norm is given by $\| F \|_2 = \| [a\ b]^T \|_2 = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.
Now we consider the space $\mathbb{R}^2$ endowed with the 2-norm of vectors. A vector $v = (a, b)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a norm $\| v \|_2 = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.
We can define a bijective linear function $\phi: L(\mathbb{R}^2) \to \mathbb{R}^2$. Since $\phi([a\ b]^T) = (a, b)$, we will show that $\phi$ preserves the norm. For $\forall F \in L(\mathbb{R}^2)$, by its matrix $[a\ b]^T$, we have:
\begin{align*}
    \| \phi([a\ b]^T) \|_2 &= \|(a, b)\|_2, \\
    &= \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}.
\end{align*}
The function $\phi$ is also linear, as it preserves the operations of addition and scalar multiplication. Let $[a\ b]^T$ and $[c\ d]^T$ be two matrices in $L(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $k$ a scalar. We have:
\begin{align*}
    \phi([a\ b]^T + [c, d]^T) &= \phi([a + c\ b + d]^T), \\
    &= (a + c, b + d), \\
    &= (a, b) + (c, d), \\
    &= \phi([a\ b]^T) + \phi([c, d]^T).
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \phi(k[a\ b]^T) &= \phi([ka\ kb]^T), \\
    &= (ka, kb), \\
    &= k(a, b), \\
    &= k\phi([a\ b]^T).
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\phi$ is a bijective linear function that preserves the 2-norm.

The norm on $R^2$ shouldn't matter, because all norms on a given $R^n$ are equivalent.

Why is the norm on $F$ as you have written? For $F:R^2\to R$ we should evaluate $|F| = \sup |ax+by|$ subject to $x^2+y^2=1$.

@AlvinL I had thought that I could evaluate the norm of F as that of a vector, but thinking about it, it is a linear transformation. I think it's wrong.

Using the suggestion of Lagrange Multiplier Method of @AlvinL. We can represent it by a $2 \times 1$ matrix representing its coefficients.
Let F(x, y) = ax + by , then the p-norm is
\begin{align*}
    \|F\|_p = \sup_{\|x\|_p = 1} \|F(x)\|_p = \sup_{\|x\|_p = 1} \|ax + by\|_p = \sup_{\|x\|_p = 1} ax + by.
\end{align*}
We can apply the Lagrangian because we want to maximize $( ax + by )$ with the constraint $( \|x\|_p = 1 )$
$$
L(x, y, \lambda) = ax + by + \lambda(1 - x^p - y^p),
$$
\begin{align*}
    L_x(x,y,\lambda) &= a - p\lambda x^{p-1} \\
    L_y(x,y,\lambda) &= b - p\lambda y^{p-1} \\
    L_\lambda(x,y,\lambda) &= 1 - x^p - y^p
\end{align*}
By calculating the derivatives and setting them to zero, we have
\begin{align*}
    x &= \left(\frac{a}{p \lambda}\right)^\frac{1}{p-1} \\
    y &= \left(\frac{b}{p \lambda}\right)^\frac{1}{p-1}
\end{align*}
Substituting into $x^p + y^p = 1$ and remembering that $q = \frac{p}{p-1}$
\begin{align*}
    \left(\frac{a}{p \lambda}\right)^\frac{p}{p-1} + \left(\frac{b}{p \lambda}\right)^\frac{p}{p-1} = 1 &\Leftrightarrow \left(\frac{a}{p \lambda}\right)^q + \left(\frac{b}{p \lambda}\right)^q = 1 \\
    &\Leftrightarrow \frac{a^q + b^q}{p^q \lambda^q} = 1 \\
    &\Leftrightarrow p^q \lambda^q = a^q + b^q \\
    &\Leftrightarrow \lambda = \frac{(a^q + b^q)^\frac{1}{q}}{p}
\end{align*}
Substituting into ( x ) and ( y )
\begin{align*}
    x &= \left(\frac{a}{(a^q + b^q)^\frac{1}{q}}\right)^\frac{1}{p-1} \\
    y &= \left(\frac{b}{(a^q + b^q)^\frac{1}{q}}\right)^\frac{1}{p-1}
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
    \|F\|_p &= a \cdot \left(\frac{a}{(a^q + b^q)^\frac{1}{q}}\right)^\frac{1}{p-1} + b \cdot \left(\frac{b}{(a^q + b^q)^\frac{1}{q}}\right)^\frac{1}{p-1} \\
    &= \frac{1}{(a^q + b^q)^\frac{1}{q(p-1)}} \left( a^{\frac{1}{p-1} + 1} + b^{\frac{1}{p-1} + 1} \right) \\
    &= \frac{\left( a^q + b^q \right)}{(a^q + b^q)^\frac{1}{q(p-1)}} \\
    &= \left(a^q + b^q\right)^{1 - \frac{1}{p}} \\
    &= \left(a^q + b^q\right)^\frac{p - 1}{p} \\
    &= \left(a^q + b^q\right)^\frac{1}{q} = \|(a, b)\|_q \quad \quad \blacksquare
\end{align*}
